# change login part

Tags: magento2

I'm new in Magento. 
I've made a web site https://tangs.com.au and I've add a Sign In plus register links to my header.

How can I change these links to something else? 
For example show there "my account" instead of Sign in?

http://joxi.ru/D2P8Pb0IpwnY52

I'm sure that it should be simple with using some php function but I'm really bad in programming so if anyone could help me with a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are just wanting to change the text rather than where the links point?

If so, the least-effort approach for a stand-alone store is probably to use inline translation.

In Magento 2, go to `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate Inline` and set `Enabled for storefront` to `Yes`.

The front end of the site will then have buttons next to each bit of text, via which you can update the text displayed.

It is important that you also add your IP to `Developer Client Restrictions` so that no one else can edit your site when this is turned on.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. However, it is not exactly what I need. I have a <div> with links <a href="https://[MYSITE]/customer/account/login/">Sign in</a> and what I want is to change this "sign in" link to (for example) "my account" link ONLY when customer is signed in to the web-site. Is it possible to do?